# Why is there only activity on 2 of my 8 cores?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu

I have a computer with two cpus with 4 cores each (physical) but htop is only showing activity on two of these 8 cores (number 1 and 3)!? Also, if I run "stress -c 8" top shows only 25% cpu usage. I've rebooted the machine and the problem persists. I also took a look at the BIOS settings and found nothing there that looked suspicious.

I've never heard of a hardware failure that manifests itself like this. I'd imagine that a HW failure like this would result in crashes so I'm suspecting some weird kernel problem since I just updated to Ubuntu 14.10 but that also seems highly unlikely somehow.

Is anybody familiar with this type of problem?

Below are some relevant hardware specs from lshw:

```
 *-cpu:0
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 400
      bus info: cpu@0
      slot: CPU
      size: 2666MHz
      capacity: 3800MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
      configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 700
         size: 32KiB
         capacity: 32KiB
         capabilities: internal write-back data
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 701
         size: 12MiB
         capacity: 12MiB
         capabilities: internal varies unified
 *-cpu:1
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 401
      bus info: cpu@1
      slot: CPU
      size: 2666MHz
      capacity: 3800MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1333MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
      configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 702
         size: 32KiB
         capacity: 32KiB
         capabilities: internal write-back data
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 703
         size: 12MiB
         capacity: 12MiB
         capabilities: internal varies unified
```

Comment: Things just got even weirder! If I run 'stress -c 8' only two cores go to 100% in htop as stated above (cores 1 and 3). If I run 'stress -c 1', one core goes to 100% (either core 1 or 3). If I run taskset -cp <coreid> <pid> I can control which core the process is run on. So get this... I can actually move it to any core that I want! So the cores are there... the kernel just doesn't seem to use it unless I explicitly tell it to put a process on it!?

Comment: Some more info. I've verified that this is a regression when moving from [lxk]ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. I used pristine lubuntu 14.10 and 14.04 usb sticks to test this out and verified that a cpu sysbench test using 8 threads took ~15 sec on 14.04 but ~55 sec on 14.10. The computer this is happening on is a Dell Precision T5400 tower workstation. As mentioned above it has two Intel Xeon E5430 quad core cpus.
I'm filing a bug for this.

Comment: Bug report has been filed:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1386473

Answer (score -2):

If you look in your bios under performance you should see a setting for hyper-threading, if it is disabled enable it, if that doesn't help go back to your bios and look for multi core support set it to all if it isn't already, reboot and it should be fixed

Comment: This was a kernel scheduling bug and had nothing to do with hyperthreading as you can see in the bug report filed:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1386473